# GIt Replaces Local Files With LFS Links

Tags: windows, git, unity-game-engine, git-lfs

I have had git LFS enabled on my repository for a while and it has always worked perfectly. Recently, I have been having issues where my local files are being replaced with links.

As an example, I have a png file that will no longer open because the file format is not supported. Upon opening the file in notepad, I am presented with this.

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:733c51c9ee6f0f395f5f042869307154d6ebf6d5d5e3bc10e2af68a432903bf0
size 5104
```

Many of my files are being replaced with these links and my programs that are accessing these files are throwing errors as they are unable to read them.

I am working in Windows 10, I have git lfs installed, I am using git-bash on the Windows Cmd line. I believe that when I was installing git-bash, I enabled symbolic links, I am unsure if that could potentially be causing the issue.

If you need more information, please let me know. I really appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: Did you try running [`git lfs fetch`](https://www.mankier.com/1/git-lfs-fetch) eventually also `git lfs fetch origin --all`?

Comment: When you use git-lfs, that's what git-lfs actually has Git store. If you take a git-lfs repository and use it with plain Git instead of with git-lfs, that's what you'll see, because that's what is in Git. The git-lfs wrappers normally hide this from you by spotting these files and replacing the one you see with the file that's stored somewhere *other* than in Git. So it looks like you've run plain Git instead of git-lfs, but perhaps there's some way to mis-configure git-lfs to cause this too.

Comment: I just ran `git lfs fetch` and then `git lfs pull` and it seems to have worked! Thank you very much for that, I did not realize that lfs had a separate push and pull system.

Answer (score 4):

These are the pointer files that Git LFS uses to track objects. The fact that you're seeing them means that the proper filters for your repository aren't set up. Run `git lfs install` within your checkout to install the filters both in your repository and in your `~/.gitconfig`.

Once you've done that, you can run `git lfs checkout` to fix the current repository, and then Git LFS should work normally when you check out a branch. If you modify or replace your `~/.gitconfig` file, be sure to keep the filter entries that `git lfs install` inserted there.

The proper commands to set the options are as follows:

```
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

It's much easier to invoke `git lfs install`, though.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more what needs to be done in ~/.gitconfig in particular for the LFS?

Comment: Updated to reflect the option settings.  `git lfs env` will also show you the options for this.