# Accessing Git LFS link? Git LFS link replaces with LFS pointer files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I needed to keep a 60MB binary file with Git LFS. The link worked for 6 days,

```
wget https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/raqueeb/datasets/master/bnwiki-texts.zip
```

Now, wget says file not found.

After getting to the file location, it actually replaced with git LFS pointer like this,

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:3122a4b0b3e76820f656cce6a5b65ff802666d238c04d152ee0b3ab0bc083ef6
size 61696513
```

After reading the documentation, it seems two problem, 1. I need to redo and "run git lfs clean" or "git lfs pointer" and "git lfs checkout" 2. [GIt Replaces Local Files With LFS Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55730590/git-replaces-local-files-with-lfs-links)

I don't get this. How the link worked for 6 days and now it doesn't? And, how to correct the link? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you're using there is for Git LFS, but your repository isn't using Git LFS for storing that object.  Your object in the repo is a native Git object and you don't have a .gitattributes file, which is required for using Git LFS.

You should probably use a non-LFS link if you want to download files from that repository.  You can find such a link in the web interface.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I deleted the whole repo along with .gitattributes file and did the same thing with native Git object as it is within 100mb. Seems like Git LFS isn't working as expected.

You are right. I should have used non-LFS link, but my question remains what happens when I have more than 100mb files. I'll have to use LFS. 

I still have no clue what has gone wrong for that. What if I have a git LFS and it gives me pointer than that of actual object? How do I fix the link? I still can't figure out how active link converted to LFS pointer.

Comment: Now, the link is changed from https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/ to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ as it is native git object.

Comment: The link you get from the web UI should continue to work.  However, since the link is different for LFS and non-LFS data, if you change whether the file is LFS or non-LFS, then the link will break.